# Excel, get the nth result from a named range of sheets

Tags: arrays, excel, named-ranges

I have a multi sheet workbook. Each sheet has a column with data I am interested in. Sheets 1,3,5 fulfill the criteria which in this example means they contain a 1. I have a named range of my sheet names, called SheetList and I am trying to find the nth sheet in SheetList that has data I am interested in.

I am trying to use this formula (to find the second sheet

`{=SMALL(IF((COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!A:A"),1)>0) = TRUE,ROW((COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!A:A"),1)>0))-ROW(INDEX((COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!A:A"),1)>0),1)) + 1),2)}`

but it has an error. The components seem to be correct and I can work around the error but I would prefer that it works. I have attached [a screenshot of my workings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIFtT.png):

Bools is a named range of A2:A6

e: [standard error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxd3H.png)

e2: the error is due to the ROW(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!A:A"),1)>0) I am not sure how to get around this

e3: Answer: I want Row(SheetList), e2 has an underlying #REF! error

Comment: What error is it?

Comment: standard one, s/s attached

Comment: To be clear, the `{}` in the formulas aren't in there manually, correct? Those are placed when you use `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Comment: yeah that is correct. the result of the formula is in the cells below